# How to get the last json date

Tags: php, json

i have a json file that has items, and each item  has dates, so every date size is different.

This is an example

```
    "History": [
      "2018-11-07",
      "2018-11-24",
      "2019-01-10",
      "2019-02-15",
      "2019-08-30",
      "2019-09-12",
      "2019-10-11"
    ],
```

Is possible to get only the dates before last? (ex: last is 2019-10-11, and get the 2019-09-12)

Comment: what are you try to do ?!!

Comment: I want the "last date -1"

Comment: so you want the second last item of your array, is your array already sorted?

Comment: well you have to start something first, to summarize, you need to open and get the contents of the file then decode it, once its an array, sort it then get the count - 1 and use as index and viola!

Comment: @Kevin: count - 2*

Comment: @catcon yep,correction to OP, my comment above summarizes the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether your array is sorted so I just assume it is unsorted.

```
// turn your json to an array and sort it
$json = '{"History" : [
    "2018-11-07",
      "2018-11-24",
      "2019-01-10",
      "2019-02-15",
      "2019-09-12",
      "2019-08-30",
      "2019-10-11"
    ]
}';

$date = json_decode($json, true);

function sortDate($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}

usort($date['History'], 'sortDate');

print_r($date);

// get the second last item
echo $date['History'][count($date['History']) - 2];
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [History] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-11-07
            [1] => 2018-11-24
            [2] => 2019-01-10
            [3] => 2019-02-15
            [4] => 2019-08-30
            [5] => 2019-09-12
            [6] => 2019-10-11
        )

)

2019-09-12
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/35OoR

Comment: The problem is the History updates, so it can add dates, so i can't add myself the dates, can i get that with "$response['History'];" ?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
    $json = '{"History" : [
            "2018-11-07",
              "2018-11-24",
              "2019-01-10",
              "2019-02-15",
              "2019-09-12",
              "2019-08-30",
              "2019-10-11"
            ]
        }';

    $php_array = json_decode($json);
    echo $php_array->History[count($php_array->History) - 2];
```